# Hide a certain character in an input field jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, hide

I am trying to hide a dollar sign in an input field.
I am populating the input field with some values from buttons, so when you click on the button it will populate the field, but it is still showing the dollar sign still for some reason. Some help will be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Here is my fiddle - [http://jsfiddle.net/7Shzg/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/7Shzg/) and the code bellow

```
$('#amount').html($('#amount').html().replace("$",""));

$( "button" ).click(function() {
        var text = $( this ).text();
             $( "#amount" ).val( text );
            });
```

Comment: you've two elements with same Id in fiddle?

Comment: I don't think your first line of code is doing anything, can't you remove that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this : replace `$` with empty space while reading text value. Also you got two element with same id in jsfiddle. put id = "amount" for input box.

HTML :

```
<label>Sum:</label>
    <input type="text" id="amount" name="amount">

    <ul id="money"> 
          <li>$500</li>
          <li>$1000</li>
    </ul>
```

jQuery :

```
$( "#money li" ).click(function() {
   var text = $( this ).text().replace('$','');
   $( "#amount" ).val( text );
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7Shzg/4/)**